# How to ADD sibling directory to Docker image

Tags: docker, fig

Is there a way to copy a sibling directory into my docker image, i.e., something like

`ADD ../sibling_directory /usr/local/src/web/`

This is not permitted - according to the Docker documentation, all resources accessible by my Dockerfile must be under the Dockerfile working directory.

In my scenario, I am in the process of splitting out worker services from web services from a common code base, and I'd like to do that logically first without having to actually physically separate the code.

Comment: Like you said all files relevant for dockers build context need to be in the same dir as the Dockerfile. I guess one option would be to wrap the `docker build` command in a shell script which copies the relevant files from your sibling_directory before docker build -t .. is run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what a potential `fig.yml` might look like:

```
web:
    build: ./web/
    volumes:
     - /usr/local/src/web/
worker:
    build: ./worker/
    volumes_from:
     - web
```

Comment: My fig.yml looks like this: http://pastebin.com/6HK1u7En But my problem remains - how to copy web into worker at build time.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an abbreviated version that shows how you can use `volumes` and `volumes_from` to do it when you run your stack.